# Ganglia Running but Not Showing CPUs or Hosts

Tags: debian, system-monitoring, ganglia

So I just set up ganglia on a single debian node. It followed a pretty simple process of

1 - installed from stable repo using

```
apt-get install ganglia-monitor gmetad
apt-get install ganglia-webfrontend
```

2 - configured using using: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/introduction-to-ganglia-on-ubuntu-14-04#installation

Now I have everything running and I can access it on localhost/ganglia and it shows the grid memory, network, and load but not CPU. The CPU total is 0, hosts up and down are 0 and there is no avg load or utilization.

Just to be clear this is debian wheezy, I am only running it on a single node that is running both gmetad and gmond so thus reporting to itself. Is there further setup I need to do or does anyone know what could be the cause of this problem and lack of information?

Answer (score 1):

Strangely this isn't well documented or possibly I just did a poor job finding the docs but I had to change `/etc/ganglia/gmond.conf` to this, restart everything, and now it works just fine:

```
  udp_send_channel {
    host = 127.0.0.1
    port = 8649
    ttl = 1
  }

  udp_recv_channel {
    port = 8649
    family = inet4
  }
  udp_recv_channel {
    port = 8649
    family = inet6
  }
```

Hopefully this helps anyone else who was setting up a single node and master!

PS in the same file don't forget to change `mcast_join = 127.0.0.1` to `host = 127.0.0.1`

Comment: I tried it and in udp_send_channel the host with 127.0.0.1 is critical as localhost did not work for me